# Best practices for linking with X11 libraries

Tags: makefile, portability

I have an X11 app I developed on a RedHat box. When I moved to CentOS, the X11 libraries moved as well. From `/usr/X11R6/lib64` to `/usr/X11R6/lib` (even though both were running 64-bit), and I have seen them elsewhere on other Linux/Unix systems.

I had used the `-I` and `-L` compile flags to point to the X11 lib directories directly in the makefile, but have since realized, this requires changes to the makefile when switching machines.

My question is, for the sake of portability... should I keep using `-I` and `-L` in the makefile? And if so, is there a way to detect the location automatically? Or, should I just rely on the user having these in their LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're relying on GNU make, you could do something like:

```
X11LIBS ?= $(word 1, $(dir $(wildcard /usr/X11R6/lib64/libX11.so.*)))
X11LIBS ?= $(word 1, $(dir $(wildcard /usr/X11R6/lib/libX11.so.*)))
X11LIBS ?= $(word 1, $(dir $(wildcard /usr/lib/libX11.so.*)))
# and so on for whatever paths you come across

LDFLAGS += -L$(X11LIBS) -R$(X11LIBS)
```

This allows the user to override X11LIBS on the command line (`make X11LIBS=/usr/local/X11R6/lib`), and tries a couple of locations if no user option is given.

You could even abort the build if no path is found, like

```
 ifeq ($(X11LIBS),)
 $(error Could not find X11 library path, please specify in X11LIBS
 endif
```

All this is only an option if you're content with restricting the Makefile's portability: non-GNU make very likely won't be happy with these macros.